# Source Control MySQL Stored Procedure to TFS 2015

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I'm tasked to Source control the mysql stored procedures to TFS 2015. I'm trying to use Visual studio 2015 to source control it.
I have been seeing blog/questions/forums about MS SQl server SProc source controled to TFS 2015 through Visual studio 2015 (Create a SQl server database project and import the SProc).
I'm unable to connect or change to mysql provider in Connection properties( in Database project)[image]

Is there another way to source control mysql Stored proc to TFS 2015?
Please help me know, what Am i Missing?
Please suggest free tools only

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **MySQL for Visual Studio** for the connection in VS.

1. Try to install the **[mysql .net connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)**
2. [Install and Configur](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html) for **MySQL for Visual Studio**
3. [Making a Connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html)

The check if you can connect the MySql in the project.

Comment: Thank you for considering to reply. I have done all the above said steps.The connections have been made. But How do I connect to TFS2015 from server explorer and upload the Stored Proc?

Comment: @SaraDob Similar as SQL server, try to create a Database project and add in source control, then connect to MySql, import the SProc.